# Typescript not respecting components defaultProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm having trouble figuring out what's going wrong here:

```js
export type PackageLanguage = "de" | "en";
export interface ICookieConsentProps {
    language?: PackageLanguage ;
}

function CookieConsent({ language }: ICookieConsentProps) {
    useEffect(() => {
        LanguageHelper.setLanguageFile(language || "en"); <--- PROBLEM HERE !
    }, [language]);

    return <div className="cc__gimme-cookies"></div>;
}

CookieConsent.defaultProps = {
    language: "en",
} as Partial<ICookieConsentProps>;
```

I'd like to use the language property in some function. Why does TypeScript ignore the defaultProps I've set for the language prop and want's me to check for undefined?

`LanguageHelper.setLanguageFile(language);`
Argument of type 'PackageLanguage | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PackageLanguage'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'PackageLanguage'.ts(2345)

`LanguageHelper.setLanguageFile(language || "en");`
This works fine but is kinda redundant, since I defined defaultProps.

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Kind Regards,
Andreas | asdf1414

Comment: Why not use default destructuring values (`{ language = "en" }: ICookieConsentProps`)

Comment: It seems a lot cleaner to me, since I use around 10 props in total and don't want the default values hanging somewhere around there

Comment: TypeScript is not aware that `defaultProps` affects the function's call signatures, so unfortunately this is probably one of the best ways to solve it.

Comment: Ah I see, what a bummer. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `language` is typed as optional so conceivably could be undefined.

You could look at combining `Pick` and `Required` utility functions to get the result you need.

```
export type PackageLanguage = "de" | "en";
export interface ICookieConsentProps {
    language?: PackageLanguage;
    otherProp: string;
    propNotInterestedIn: string;
}

type Props = Pick<ICookieConsentProps, 'language' | 'otherProp'>

function CookieConsent({ language }: Required<Props>) {
    useEffect(() => {
        LanguageHelper.setLanguageFile(language || "en"); <--- PROBLEM HERE !
    }, [language]);

    return <div className="cc__gimme-cookies"></div>;
}

CookieConsent.defaultProps = {
    language: "en",
    otherProp: "another prop"
} as Required<Props>;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mention that I have more than one prop (around 10) but I only need a few inside defaultProps since the others are not optional. Is there any way to combine the Required and Partial somehow?

Comment: Maybe something using `Pick` and `Required` - see update.

Comment: Seems to work, but for the sake of my personal taste, I'll be using the input from @kellys and move the default values directly into the prop detructuring. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Whatever works for you!